# Can I use an Angular 5 (Not AngularJS) application in HTML iframe?

Tags: angular, iframe

I want to integrate Angular (Not AngularJS) application into my website. Can I use the HTML iFrame in my website and point 'src' attribute to angular application URL? Will that work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use HTML Iframe to show Angular/Any other Website.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Yes

### Long answer

> [The HTML Inline Frame element (iframe) represents a nested browsing
>   context, embedding another HTML page into the current one.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

This means that when you set the url on the `iframe`, all content of the url will be downloaded an putted on the `iframe` (images, html, css, javascript, etc etc) as the browser do when you access a given url.

Also, Angular is just a framework to convert a Typescript/HTML/SCSS into pure javascript, html and css. It not really matters if you are using angular, vue, react. All these frameworks are compiled to languages(HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT) that the browser could interpret.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo. I was going through forms and came across the HTML <link rel="import" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/stuff.html">. If I use HTML import, will I be able to do two way communicate with host site and the site in HTML import?